# Isolation of voltmeter via DC->AC->DC conversion

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-measurement, isolation, common-mode

I bought a [combination ammeter/voltmeter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005HBBZEM) which has the restriction that the measurement/display circuitry must be powered from a different source than the measured voltage.

What is the underlying cause of this restriction (if there is a general underlying cause)?

More specifically, if I power this unit from an AC->DC wall-wart where the AC comes from a DC->AC inverter powered on the DC side from the same voltage source that I'm measuring, will this provide sufficient isolation for the unit to work?

Comment: Do you have a link to a technical document for that product?

Comment: @Andyaka - for the meter, no - the only document is a single small sheet of paper which has the hookup diagram. For the inverter, the manual and data sheet on on the sidebar [here](http://www.xantrex.com/power-products/power-inverters/prowatt-sw.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If your wall-wart is isolated (and has no ground pin) then this should work. Make sure that there is no continuity to either plug prong from the wall-wart ground.